# Sql's query analyzer for visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I do a lot of mistakes in sql query in visual studio 2008. is there any addin, which can analyze my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write them in Query Analyzer first and copy them across (or even better, stick them in stored procedures or write LINQ queries to get SQL strings out of your codebase altogether).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of mistakes do you maken? It is typo's or not knowing what keywords you can use , then you could use a intellisense tool like [SQLAssist](http://roundpolygons.com/)

Comment: i missed commas, sometimes keyword like "FROM"